# ktor websocket listener for new message

Tags: ktor

Is there a way to run some code each time a ktor websocket receives a new message, kind of like [onTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) in Android views?

Currently I check for new messages and process them in a while loop as follows:

```kotlin
while (websocketIsOpen) {
    val newMessage = session!!.incoming.receive()

    processMessage(newMessage)
}
```

where `session` is a [`DefaultClientWebsocketSession?`](https://api.ktor.io/1.5.2/io.ktor.client.features.websocket/-default-client-web-socket-session/index.html), and `processMessage` is a method that has a `Frame` as a parameter.

I would prefer to set code that runs each time a new message is received, something like the following:

```kotlin
session!!.incoming.onNewMessage = { newMessage ->
    processMessage(newMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `consumeEach` method of the incoming frames channel to run some code when a frame is received:

```
webSocket("/") {
    incoming.consumeEach { frame ->
        if (frame is Frame.Text) {
            println("They say ${frame.readText()}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!!